# Changing search box height in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code to change the width and height of a search box :

```
 .input-mysize {   
   height: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   width: 250px; }
```

I am able to change only the width of the search box. Can you tell me how to change the height? The code of the search box is this :

```
       <input class="search-query input-mysize"  name="search_query" type="text" placeholder="Make a search" >
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default height of the twitter bootstrap input text is 20px with 4px from top and bottom padding.

So when you say 20px, you don't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the Bootstrap styling so this is just a guess...

The Bootstrap styles might be outweighing yours, or they could be added dynamically. Try adding `!important` to the end of your height style.